# Converting String (Textbox.text) to DateTime with current time

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to convert this e.g. 12/31/2012 format into DateTime, however when I run this code the conversion works but the time is not current. I am looking to convert to DateTime but with the current time:

Example: When I run the below code and enter date: 12/31/2012

I get: 12/31/2012 12:00:00 AM

I am not sure how to get the current time instead of 12:00:00 AM

```
    Console.Write("Enter Current Date: ");

    string strMyDate = Console.ReadLine();

    DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(strMyDate);

    Console.WriteLine(dt);

    Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can extract only the time from `DateTime.Now` by using the `TimeOfDay` property and add it to your manually entered date, e.g.

```
var time = dt.Add(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);
```

As an additional note, I would use *DateTime.TryParse* instead, as the value entered by the user may not be a parseable date, e.g.

```
DateTime dt;
var isDate = DateTime.TryParse(strMyDate, out dt);
if(isDate)
{
   var time = dt.Add(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! These are all valuable solutions. Now I know somethings I never knew before. Someday I hope to return these favors but for now, I am still a blind mad, metaphorically. Thank you George!

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.Now` will give you current time. Than combine date portion from first value with time portion from `Now` to get the result.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your string:

```
string strMyDate = Console.ReadLine();
strMyDate = string.Format("{0} {1}",
    strMyDate,
    DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Haven't actually compiled this but something like this should work:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("12/31/2012 " + DatTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build up the time from the hours, minutes and seconds portion of DateTime.Now;

```
string strMyDate = "12/31/2012";
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(strMyDate);
DateTime current = DateTime.Now;
dt = dt.AddHours(current.Hour).AddMinutes(current.Minute).AddSeconds(current.Second);
Console.WriteLine(dt);
```